# record a sound within custom application of iPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to develop an application in which voice can be recorded & data should be displayed after filtering accordingly recorded voice.

I want to do the same thing in my Application.

My Application requirements are as follows. 
=> search entries accordingly recorded voice?

for me,

1) How to record a sound?   ----- More Priority
2) If recorded then how to compare sounds through entire entries?  -- Less Priority

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link guide us how to record sound within our application.

when i didn't get any answer from stack overflow,

i tried my self.

so,i go through net search engines & i found following link,

http://www.tuaw.com/2007/08/06/iphone-coding-recording-audio/

Comment: Huh ! They have removed their link of the code -- now what should I do?